# Creating point from lat / lon values stored in two fields?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4, oracle-dbms, st-geometry

I'm trying to create a point from latitude & longitude values stored in two fields (lat, lon). I need to perform a transform to get the point from its source coordinate system into the coordinate system of the shape field. When I hardcode the lat/lon values the SQL statement works. When I try to concatenate the field names the SQL throws an error.

-- hardcoded values works:

```
INSERT INTO table_pt (objectid, shape) VALUES (1, sde.st_transform(sde.st_geometry('point (-90.012345 45.012345)', 1), 2, 3));
```

-- reading values from fields does not work:

```
INSERT INTO table_pt (objectid, shape) VALUES (1, sde.st_transform(sde.st_geometry('point ( ' || lon || ' ' || lat || ' )', 1), 2, 3));
```

and results in this error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

How do I create a point from lat / lon values stored in two fields?

Comment: You do not appear to be using ArcGIS Desktop to do this so I removed the tag for that.  If you were you could make an XY event layer and export it to get points.

Comment: @PolyGeo - that is correct. This SQL will be run from code against an Oracle 12 database with ArcSDE 10.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "stored in two fields" ? Are they in another table ? If so you need to use an INSERT ... SELECT approach.

Assume you have a table with the values like this:

```
create table pts (id number, lon number, lat number);
```

You do your insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_pt (objectid, shape) 
select id, sde.st_transform(sde.st_geometry('point ( ' || lon || ' ' || lat || ' )', 1), 2, 3)
from pts;
```

Or do you mean that the long/lat columns are in the same table as your geometry column, like this ?

```
create table table_pt (object_id number, lon number, lat number, shape sde.st_geometry);
```

Then you need a simple update

```
update table_pt 
set shape = sde.st_transform(sde.st_geometry('point ( ' || lon || ' ' || lat || ' )', 1), 2, 3);
```

If you mean that `lon` and `lat` are variables in your application code, then you need to use bind variables. The way that works depends on the language you use (java, python, PL/SQL ...)